# Does DotNetNuke support ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, dotnetnuke

I'm going to build a web app. I need some CMS that can be integrated with ASP.NET MVC.

The possible solution list is:
1)  Oxite
2)  MVC CMS
3)  AtomSite
4)  N2.

Sorry for obvious question, but can the DotNetNuke be used with ASP.NET MVC? TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, DotNetNuke is built on ASP.Net WebForms and relies heavily on ViewState.  So, at the moment, it doesn't run on ASP.Net MVC.

Answer (score 3):

Should you use ASP NET MVC in your application, i would recommend you to have some looks to Kooboo CMS ( kooboo.codeplex.com). This CMS is an ASP NET MVC CMS application and can be used to create asp net MVC web application as well.

Answer (score 0):

Charles Nurse shows how to make this work in a three part blog series:

1. http://www.charlesnurse.com/post/Developing-Modules-for-DotNetNuke-using-ASPNET-MVC-Part-1-Introduction.aspx
2. http://www.charlesnurse.com/post/Developing-Modules-for-DotNetNuke-using-ASPNET-MVC-Part-2-The-ASPNET-MVC-Pipeline.aspx
3. http://www.charlesnurse.com/post/Developing-Modules-for-DotNetNuke-using-ASPNET-MVC-Part-3-The-MvcModuleApplication-Class.aspx